# Can't log in to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, crash

I had a c++ program which creates .data files. I accidentally clicked its executable file directly instead of running it through an IDE. It kept on making files without opening any console. The system hanged and I turned it off by pushing the power button. Now every time I try to login, it just freezes and brings back the login page again. I already tried .Xauthority, /tmp, and lightdm solutions, but none of them work. Any solutions?

Comment: Hi, what kind of C++ program was it? It would be good if you show us the code for the program. At first sight, it seems you may have corrupted some OS files, and some recovery procedure would be the quickest solution.

Comment: Can you log in with a virtual console (e.g. Ctrl + Alt + F2)? If your program just filled your drive up to 100% (possible if you ran it as root), it would be easy to clean using the console. If that fails, mounting the partitions using a USB/CD live system would allow you for sure to delete files.

Comment: What user were you running it as?